# LuaLaTeX : passing test condition n~=3 to lua as macro parameter problem

Tags: luatex, extended-characters, active-characters

I try to pass `lua` test condition as `latex` macro parameter and have a problem in case of `~=` with the next error message. How to avoid that.

> ! LuaTeX error [\directlua]:1: invalid escape sequence near '\p'.
>   \test ... until assert(load("return ".. fin))() }
>
> l.20 \test[n~=3]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{luacode}

\newcommand{\test}[1][n==3]{%

    \directlua{%
    fin = "#1"
    repeat
        n=math.random(1,5)
        tex.print (n.." ")
    until assert(load("return ".. fin))()
    }
}

\begin{document}

\test   % ok
\test[n>=3 and n<=8]    % ok

\test[n~=3] % gives the error message above

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\directlua` expands input in an `\edef`-like fashion. You should always watch for expansion: here we have `~`, which is expanded if you don't protect it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}    
\newcommand{\test}[1][n==3]{%
    \directlua{%
      local fin = "\unexpanded{#1}"
      repeat
        n = math.random(1,5)
        tex.print(n .. " ")
      until assert(load("return ".. fin))()
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\test   % ok
\test[n>=3 and n<=8]    % ok

\test[n~=3] % gives the error message above

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've also used a local variable here: good Lua style